# How to mock a cloned imports dependency differently in each test

Tags: unit-testing, ecmascript-6, mocking, jestjs

I have a file that imports another. I want to mock the other import differently in each test yet have it show through the file that imports it.

I have tried various mocking and importing approaches through googling but none have worked.

Consider the files:

> settings.js

```
export default { mySetting: null };
```

> store.js

```
import settings from "./settings";
export default {
  settings: { ...settings },
};
```

> settingsDemo.js

```
import store from "./store";

it("default settings", () => {
  expect(store.settings.mySetting).toBe(null);
});

it("mocked to true", () => {
  expect(store.settings.mySetting).toBe(true);
});

it("mocked to false", () => {
  expect(store.settings.mySetting).toBe(false);
});
```

how do I mock these files within `settingsDemo.js` to have all 3 tests pass without editing `settings.js` or `store.js`?

Note:
this is similar to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52750813/how-to-mock-an-imports-dependency-differently-in-each-test/), but the solution to import the dependency and change the value doesn't work in this case since `store` doesn't reference the `settings` object here but instead clones it for an initial value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same principle applies: ["while you can't change the value of imports, you can change the objects that they are referring to."](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html#_in-es6-imports-are-live-read-only-views-on-exported-values)

In this case `store` is an object that contains a nested `settings` object.  While it is not possible to simply assign `store` to something else, it is possible to assign `store.settings` to something else.  It is also possible to set `store.settings.mySetting` to something else:

```
import store from "./store";

it("default settings", () => {
  expect(store.settings.mySetting).toBe(null);  // SUCCESS
});

it("mocked to true", () => {
  store.settings = { mySetting: true };  // set store.settings to something else
  expect(store.settings.mySetting).toBe(true);  // SUCCESS
});

it("mocked to false", () => {
  store.settings.mySetting = false;  // set store.settings.mySetting to something else
  expect(store.settings.mySetting).toBe(false);  // SUCCESS
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question. It sounds like you just want to mock a simple object
"`{settings:{ mySetting: null }}`".

```
let store = {settings:{ mySetting: null }}

it("default settings", () => {
  store.settings.mySetting = null
  expect(store.settings.mySetting).toBe(null);
});

it("mocked to true", () => {
  store.settings.mySetting = true
  expect(store.settings.mySetting).toBe(true);
});

it("mocked to false", () => {
  store.settings.mySetting = false
  expect(store.settings.mySetting).toBe(false);
});
```